# How to manage the post order based on the below given query in wordpress and display the result on the home page?

Tags: wordpress

```
    global $wpdb;
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` ORDER BY CASE ID WHEN 64 THEN -1 ELSE ID END";
        $wpq = new WP_Query();
        $wpq->parse_query($query);
        $posts = $wpq->get_posts();

        foreach ($posts as $post){
            setup_postdata($post);
        }

            wp_reset_postdata();
```

this is a code that i am getting from the wp_post table but unable to display the given result on the home page

Comment: is CASE ID a column aswell? if so, don't use spaces in columns/tables, instead use CamelCasing or an _

Comment: query is working fine but i am able to display the query data on the home page

Comment: Also, show more code. how are you trying to display the query data? currently from what you showed me. you only save the result in a variable. you don't do anything with it.

Comment: global $wpdb;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` ORDER BY CASE ID WHEN 64 THEN -1 ELSE ID END";
        
        $wpq = new WP_Query();
        $wpq->parse_query($query);
        $posts = $wpq->get_posts();
        var_dump($posts);
        if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
            while ($posts->have_posts()) {
             $post =  $posts->the_post();
                setup_post_data($post);
            }
        }
            wp_reset_postdata();

Comment: i am getting this error                                                                                                    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function have_posts() on array in

Comment: as I said before. show the whole error. also, if you post code. you should post it with a ` in the front and a ` in the back like this `code`. can you also add the error and the full code in the original post so its easier for people to see?

Comment: global $wpdb;
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` ORDER BY CASE ID WHEN 64 THEN -1 ELSE ID END";
        $wpq = new WP_Query();
        $wpq->parse_query($query);
        $posts = $wpq->get_posts();

        foreach ($posts as $post){
            setup_postdata($post);
        }

            wp_reset_postdata();

Comment: i have update the code in this code error is not showing but the post order not displaying on the home page

Comment: Can you please edit the original post with your code and surround the code with backticks: ` like this `some code` and can you write the error it gives underneath/ above the code?

Comment: i have updated the original post